# How do I know from which site they entered our site? Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a website whose link is placed on various websites for advertisement. How can I know that the user who entered our site came from one of the websites that I advertised on in Asp.net Core ?

I know UrlReferrer can help my problem , But I don't know how?!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You put the project link in other websites, which is actually equivalent to calling your Api interface. You can obtain the corresponding website by receiving the `Request`.

For example:

```
public string Test()
{
    Uri uriReferer = Request.GetTypedHeaders().Referer;
    return "success";
}
```

When requesting the `Test()` action from another website, I can know which website initiated the request:

[image]